# Angular: How to give an imported module access to a provider

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an imported module that I wrote which provides a service that takes an optional dependency. The fact that it happens to be optional doesn't matter. It just meant that my app didn't throw an error when it wasn't there. For example:

```
import { FooModule } from './foo.module';
import { BarService } from './bar.service';

// other imports and logic omitted...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FooModule.forRoot(options),
  ],
  providers: [
    BarService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the code above, the `FooModule` provides a `FooService` that I can use elsewhere in my app. The `FooService` has an optional dependency:

```
export interface IBarService {
  bar: (x: string) => string;
}

export const BarService = new InjectionToken<IBarService>('any compatible bar service provider');

@Injectable()
export class FooService {

  constructor(
    @Optional() @Inject(BarService) private barService?: IBarService,
  ) {
    console.log(barService)
  }
}
```

I actually provide that optional dependency (`BarService`) in my first code block. Yet, I was discovering that it was not making its way to the `FooService` inside `FooModule`.

They both have the same injection name: `BarService`.

Yet when I run the app, the console logs the `barService` as `null`.

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing this question out, I remembered the `useExisting` property of a provider. I had to import the token (with a different variable name) and then assign a provider.

```
import { FooModule, BarService as BarServiceForFoo } from './foo.module';
import { BarService } from './bar.service';

// other imports and logic omitted...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FooModule.forRoot(options),
  ],
  providers: [
    BarService,
    { provide: BarServiceForFoo, useExisting: BarService }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

> They both have the same injection name: BarService

This part is misleading because `InjectionToken` name doesn't matter for anything but debugging.

They are different tokens at this point that have nothing in common except developer's intention. `useExisting` is an option but it requires parent and all other modules that will depend on `BarService` or or implement it to depend on Foo module either.

A possible solution is to use string token, which is prone to be antipattern because it provides loose coupling and global namespace (this is the reason why token classes were introduced) but it fits current case:

```
...
{ provide: 'vendorNamespace.BarService', useExisting: BarService }
...
```

---

```
...
constructor(
  @Optional() @Inject('appNamespace.BarService') private barService?: IBarService
) {}
...
```

Another solution is to have common module that contains both provider token and an interface... which is abstract class:

```
export abstract class BarService {
  abstract bar(x: string): string;
}
```

---

```
import { BarService as AbstractBarService } from 'common';
export class BarService implements AbstractBarService { ... }
```

---

```
import { BarService as AbstractBarService } from 'common';
import { BarService } from './bar.service';

...
{ provide: AbstractBarService, useClass: BarService }
...
```

This naturally allows to inject a provider with type annotation:

```
import { BarService } from 'common';

...
constructor(
  @Optional() private barService?: BarService
) {}
...
```